# New line that is visible in both HTML and console.log

Tags: javascript, html, newline

I have this simple JavaScript:

```
function property() {
    var ua = document.getElementById('greenBack').innerHTML;
    var finals;
    finals = ua;
    if (ua.indexOf('p')) {
        finals += '<br>\n Unknown Error';
    } 
    return finals;
}
```

The problem is that I would like a newline to be shown when the function output is displayed in `console.log()` without the `<br>` tag (because `<br>` displays on the console) , but also be able to write the text "Unknown Error" to a newline in html without using `<br>`.

Is there any solution to display a newline in HTML and the console without `\n`or `<br>` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `\n` for the console output. Then, when showing the text on a HTML page, you can either:

- replace `\n` with `<br>`
- or wrap a `<pre>` tag around it which will respect white-space and newlines
- or use CSS-style `white-space: pre-wrap;` on any other HTML element

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fmyvkwrr/)

```js
$('#test').text('This\n   is\n  a\ntest');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre id="test"></pre>
```

Comment: Upvote for css ‘white-space:pre-wrap;’ ,  that was very useful thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You can print your information in a textarea. It will use the `\n` for the new line as the console

Comment: A textarea is not appropriate in this case

Comment: Then you have to format your code. There is no way for a line break that works in HTML and the console

Answer (score -1):

pre tag what you write it display all as it is including space, \n used for new line, br tag also to move to new line, some more option comes in handy when you use js literal represented as and found on key board between esc and tap button with sign ** `** variable can be put in side `${variable inside here}`.